# count in a dataframe based on two columns

Tags: r, group-by, count

Hope you can help me out.
Have a dataset df with 3 columns - personID, operationID, and a row number.

Want to make a new column(row_intend) which should count based on both personID and operationID.

In the example the fourth row shows how I would like the outcome.
Grouped by record_id, it should count based on operationID.

```
person_id <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3")
operation_id <- c("60533", "60533", "60534", "50677", "50678", "50678", "50679", "78322", "78322")
row <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
row_intend <- c("1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1")

df <- data.frame(person_id, operation_id, row, row_intend)

df
```

I would like the output to be:

```
       person_id operation_id      row       row_intend
  1         1        60533            1          1
  2         1        60533            2          1
  3         1        60534            3          2
  4         2        50677            4          1
  5         2        50678            5          2
  6         2        50678            6          2
  7         2        50679            7          3
  8         3        78322            8          1
  9         3        78322            9          1
```

I tried with group_by and mutate(row=rownumber).
But this does not take into account my second condition (count ALSO based on operation ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may group by 'person_id' and get the `match` between the operation_id and its `unique` values

```
library(dplyr)
df <-df %>%
   group_by(person_id) %>%
   mutate(row_intend2 = match(operation_id, unique(operation_id))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
> df
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  person_id operation_id row   row_intend row_intend2
  <chr>     <chr>        <chr> <chr>            <int>
1 1         60533        1     1                    1
2 1         60533        2     1                    1
3 1         60534        3     2                    2
4 2         50677        4     1                    1
5 2         50678        5     2                    2
6 2         50678        6     2                    2
7 2         50679        7     3                    3
8 3         78322        8     1                    1
9 3         78322        9     1                    1
```

Comment: Im sorry, Ive not been clear enough. I would like the output to be:

 df
  person_id operation_id row row_intend
1         1        60533   1          1
2         1        60533   2          1
3         1        60534   3          2
4         2        50677   4          1
5         2        50678   5          2
6         2        50678   6          2
7         2        50679   7          3
8         3        78322   8          1
9         3        78322   9          1

Here it counts based on both person_id and operation ID.
My row_intend is not the same as your output